# Hyperledger composer-cli error EACCESS

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm starting to build an app on Hyperledger Composer following these instructions.

When I run :

`$ npm install -g composer-cli`

the package is correctly installed here :
`/home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/composer`

However when I try to run `composer --version` I have the following error EACCESS :

`$ composer --version
/home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:90
                    throw err0;
                    ^`

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/arnaud/.composer/logs'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at Function.sync (/home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Object.exports.getLogger (/home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/composer-common/lib/log/winstonInjector.js:76:20)
    at Function._loadLogger (/home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/composer-common/lib/log/logger.js:633:25)
    at Function._setupLog (/home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/composer-common/lib/log/logger.js:531:30)
    at Function.getLog (/home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/composer-common/lib/log/logger.js:508:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/composer-common/lib/businessnetworkmetadata.js:18:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)`

How could I solve this problem ? Many thanks

Comment: The likelyhood is that at some point you ran composer using the sudo command which created those initial directories, now you are correctly not using sudo. As suggested below, you could use the chown/chmod to correct or just to be clean, you could just do `sudo rm -fr ~/.composer` to clear out the .composer directory (which is your card store) and start again.

Comment: Yes David you solved the problem ! Thank youuuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the logging error as RThatcher describes below - its trying to write to a logfile and part of that is to create the `logs` directory, but it doesn't have permissions. Did you previously do an install of Composer with 'sudo' ? what does `ls -al /home/arnaud/.composer/*` show (who owns the directories). I ask, because its strange that you can write everywhere else under your home directory (as you'd expect to, as arnaud) . Assuming of course, that you are running the `composer --version` command above, while logged in as 'arnaud' and not as another user?

Comment: Thanks Paul ! NVM was already my versions manager for Node. As you recommended, I have installed `version 8.9.4` (8.9.5 wasn't available) and I have followed ths recommendations of your link.

Comment: Now for your third item : yes I made a mistake and I installed composer with a sudo at first time. Here is the answer for `ls -al /home/arnaud/.composer/*' : -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  799 avril 24 15:12 /home/arnaud/.composer/keys.dev.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  799 avril 24 15:12 /home/arnaud/.composer/keys.tags.pub
/home/arnaud/.composer/cache:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 avril 26 10:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 avril 26 10:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13 avril 26 10:25 .htaccess

Comment: hi Arnaud, thanks I edited my original response, as clearly its only to do with permissions now. Node 8.11.x should be supported in fact (so removed comments on that bit). - so do as david_k suggested above

Comment: The problem has been solved with `sudo rm -fr ~/.composer`

Answer (score 1):

The above issue purely a permission issue, while installing composer-cli basically the folder v8.11.1 is own by different users, i.e. other than your user id. Hence we are facing this issue. 
We need to change the owner and group of the v8.11.1 folder as follows.
Navigat to the folder v8.11.1 (/home/arnaud/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1) and then verify whether the folder is user and group are your user id (arnaud). 
Surely the folder was not own by arnaud user and group. Change the folder user and group by using chown.

Answer (score 0):

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/arnaud/.composer/logs'`

This is the core error suggesting that you don't have permissions to create the logs folder on the /home/arnaud/.composer folder or that you do not have the rights to create the .composer folder in the /home/arnaud/ folder.

You should use a combination of `ls -al` , `chmod` and possibly `chown` Linux commands to investigate and resolve the permissions problem.

Comment: Thnaks, the problem has been solved with `sudo rm -fr ~/.composer`